# How to correctly call preloader function before imports in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pep8

I have config data that should be loaded before another code (because another code use it).
So, for now I see only way to do this is to call the function at the top before rest imports:

```
from Init.Loaders.InitPreLoader import InitPreLoader
# this is my config loader
InitPreLoader.load()

from World.WorldManager import WorldManager
from Init.Loaders.InitLoader import InitLoader
from Init.Registry.InitRegistry import InitRegistry
from Utils.Debug import Logger
# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
    InitLoader.load()
```

Does it possible to do this in more elegant way and avoid to violate pep8 ?

P.S. If I need to share more code please let me know

**UPD**: All my classes declared in separate files

This is PreLoader:

```
from Typings.Abstract.AbstractLoader import AbstractLoader
from Init.Registry.InitRegistry import InitRegistry
from Config.Init.configs import main_config


class InitPreLoader(AbstractLoader):

    @staticmethod
    def load(**kwargs):
        InitRegistry.main_config = main_config
```

This is Registry (where I store all my initialized data):

```
from Typings.Abstract.AbstractRegistry import AbstractRegistry


class InitRegistry(AbstractRegistry):

    main_config = None

    login_server = None

    world_server = None

    world_observer = None

    identifier_region_map = None

    region_octree_map = None
```

Parent of all classes (except `AbstractRegistry`) is `AbstractBase` class (it contains mixin):

```
from abc import ABC

from Config.Mixins.ConfigurableMixin import ConfigurableMixin


class AbstractBase(ConfigurableMixin, ABC):
    pass
```

This mixin works with `main_config` from `InitRegistry`.
Also, after PreLoader's `load` was called, I load rest data with my `InitLoader.load()` (see first code snapshot):

```
from Typings.Abstract.AbstractLoader import AbstractLoader
from Init.Registry.InitRegistry import InitRegistry
from Server.Init.servers import login_server, world_server
from World.Observer.Init.observers import world_observer
from World.Region.Init.regions import identifier_region_map, region_octree_map


class InitLoader(AbstractLoader):

    @staticmethod
    def load(**kwargs):
        InitRegistry.login_server = login_server
        InitRegistry.world_server = world_server
        InitRegistry.world_observer = world_observer
        InitRegistry.identifier_region_map = identifier_region_map
        InitRegistry.region_octree_map = region_octree_map
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? What does `InitPreLoader` holds, and what does the `load` method do/return? How do `WorldManager`, `InitLoader` etc consume whatever `InitPreLoader` offers? Are all of these classes instantiated in your main code?

Comment: @jfaccioni thanks for response, please see updated question

Comment: I assume you have good reasons as to why you're using classes as data storages instead of, say, a dictionary. Why do you need classes like `InitPreLoader`, whose only functionality is to modify a class attribute of another class, loaded from a different file, using a value coming from yet another file? Why don't you create instances of your classes and pass them around your code (encapsulation), instead of only using static methods and class variables? Sorry I don't mean to sound harsh, but it feels way too convoluted (judging from what I can see).

Comment: Maybe you could post this to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some insight.

Comment: @jfaccioni thanks for review. The only reason of why using classes is consistency. I want  classes everywhere, where data build dynamically or some actions performed. I use dicts, but only for constants. My configs stored in .yml and because I load and parse this yml files before use, I use class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for now I have found solution: I moved `from Init.Loaders.InitPreLoader import InitPreLoader` to separate file and called `InitPreLoader.load()` there. But I not like this solution, because my PyCharm IDE highlights it as unused import:

```
import Init.Init.preloader
from World.WorldManager import WorldManager
# ...
```

Maybe it is possible to improve this solution ? Or maybe another (more elegant) solition exists ?